# boost async ioservice, slow execution of a thread on linux

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am using boost asio in my application. I have created two ioservices. one for handling UDP sockets async operations, other to handle tcp async operations. on receiving data over udp socket, based on the data i will open a tcp connection to some other server. I am using async function calls in all places.

below is high level pseudo code.

```
int g_requestID ;


// boost async_recv handler
class UDPSocket
{
    UDPSocket::OnDataReceived(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred
    {
       TCPSession *pSesson = new TCPSession() ;
       g_requestID = pSesson->sendDataOverTCP(data);
    }
}

// TCP Response Callback
void tcpResponse(int reqId)
{
   if (g_requestID == reqId)
   {
      // received response for the request 
   }
}


class TCPSession
{
   boost::asio::streambuf request_;
   static int requestId ;
   boost::tcp::socket m_socket ;
   int currentsessionId = requestId ++ ;

   int sendDataOverTCP(char* address, char* data)
   {
       m_socket.async_resolve()
       return currentsessionId++ ;
   }

   void handle_resolve(const boost::system::error_code& err, tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
   {
      if (!err)
      {
         boost::asio::async_connect(m_socket, endpoint_iterator, boost::bind(&client::handle_connect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
      }
      else
      {
         std::cout << "Error: " << err.message() << "\n";
      }
   }

   void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& err)
   {
       if (!err)
       {
          // The connection was successful. Send the request.
          boost::asio::async_write(m_socket, request_, boost::bind(&client::handle_write, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
       }
       else
       {
          std::cout << "Error: " << err.message() << "\n";
       }
   }

   void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& err)
   {
      if (!err)
      {
          boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, response_, "\r\n", boost::bind(&client::handle_receive, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
      }
      else
      {
         std::cout << "Error: " << err.message() << "\n";
      }
   }

   void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& err)
   {
      if (!err)
      {
           tcpResponse(currentsessionId) ;
      }
      else
      {
          std::cout << "Error: " << err << "\n";
      }
   } 
}
```

Now Coming to my problem. in tcpResponse function, g_requestID contains garbage value. when i debugged by adding log statements, i found that sendDataOverTCP is returned after receiving tcpResponse callback. inside sendDataOverTcp, i am calling async_resolve only. it should return immediately. but it is not.

After debugging, I found following behaviour. async_resolve is working as expected. it is returning immediately. but sendDataOverTCP returns only after tcpResponse callback.

can anybody provide me solution, is it because of some thread scheduling ?

same code is working fine on windows. on linux, i am facing this issue.

I am using boost 1.53.0 on ubuntu 13.04 using virtual box

Comment: I don't see how the first few lines even constitute valid C++ code. Please post valid code that demonstrates your problem: http://sscce.org/

Comment: in question, i have provided pseudo code which summarizes my problem.

Comment: in case it wasn't clear: please don't do that. Pseudo code only creates [Red Herrings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring)

Comment: Mkkkay. The UDPSocket class still wouldn't compile on my mental compiler. Anyways, it looks somewhat more 'truthful' now